# Fabric.js Efficiency of Clipped Sprite vs. Individual Images

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, sprite, fabricjs

I intend to have a FabricJS canvas that will display potentially dozens of different graphics, which could either be served up as individual image files or a sprite. For each graphic, it's possible that particular graphic would be displayed on the canvas 0 to dozens of times. I know that FabricJS has the [clipping](http://fabricjs.com/clipping/) ability, which would make the use of sprites possible, and I know that generally speaking, sprites on the web are highly preferred over individual images, such as for CSS.

However, I've also heard of browser behaviors/quirks surrounding canvas where some optimizations that you might expect to take place, don't -- I can't find the link at the moment, but one that I recall was how large canvas-content elements out of view in Chrome would still take a considerable amount of time to be calculated/"rendered", despite not being relevant to on-screen appearance.

**So, are there any known expectations on whether *n* individual non-clipped images would be preferable/unpreferable to a sprite that's clipped *n* times for a FabricJS canvas?** In case it matters, this would not be a heavily animated FabricJS canvas; things may move when dragged, for example, but constant animation is not what's involved in this case.

Comment: According to http://caniuse.com/#feat=canvas there aren't any clipping related issues (see known issues tab). That said I think you should pick your top three platforms (chrome, ios and....android, say...) and do some basic performance testing.

Comment: @dsummersl Interestingly, caniuse.com does mention a clipping issue in Android; the bug report it links to is closed as obsolete w/out a clear resolution.

Comment: oh yes, true...reading the ticket it sounds like its probably a problem for 1/3rd of android browsers (total rough guestimate from http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Just do a test yourself to find out what slows down your PC. It depends on the PC and browser and graphics card.

I don't know anything about Fabric.js, but computer CPUs and graphics cards can handle clipping/graphic manipulation easily. You're not displaying millions of polygons like a 3D game, so you should be fine.

Here's a website that explains the CSS sprites vs individual images network performance increases: 
https://medium.com/parlay-engineering/emoji-at-scale-render-performance-of-css-sprites-vs-individual-images-f0a0a2dd8039

Comment: Thanks, but this answer doesn't satisfy the question. If need be, I can write my own tests, yes, but I asked on SO in case there's some adequate knowledge someone would share from prior experience or tests. Regarding the # of shapes, there's a noticeable difference in my experience working w/Fabric.js canvas and high hundreds or low thousands of elements, so the fact that I wouldn't be doing millions of shapes isn't comfort enough that sprites are the way to go.